# I heard that Sikkim is not safe for tourists now?

Tags: tours, guides, sikkim

News and sources said that Darjeeling issue of North East India is misleading tourists . And Doklam/China controversy with India . I am planning a tour on Dussehra for Sikkim . here http://www.tourstosikkim.com comfirmed that it is completely safe to visit Sikkim and some news are misleading and all issues are under control . I am not sure . Thanks in advance

Comment: Sikkim is always safe for the tourists. You can visit here at any time without any issue.